# Eclipse programming time

Tags: eclipse, time

I was just wondering if there is a way I could find out how long it took me to write/edit a project? 
I need that information for a project I am currently working at.
Thank you.

Comment: Eclipse does not keep track of anything like this.

Comment: Have you looked at the plugins in the Eclipse Marketplace? Eclipse doesn't provide this by default, but there may be timekeeping plugins. I've never used any, so I can't recommend any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Mylyn set of plug-ins. It may already be included in the set of plug-ins you have as it is standard with some of the packages you download from eclipse.org.

If not, [install it](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/).

Then open the task view (`Window` -> `Show View` -> `Other` -> `General` -> `Tasks`).

In Preferences (`Mylyn` / `Tasks`) check the `Time Tracking` tickbox as in this screenshot:

[image: time tracking preference]

Then in your activated task you will see a counter:

[image: task]

Create a new task and activate it.

Comment: PS Downside of this solution is it won't tell you what you did in the past, only once you start the tracking (of course that is how it should be, a bit creepy if it was tracking you without asking first ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to track your time in eclipse without using a plugin, quick google search found some eclipse plugins to keep track of time you are coding.

Here is a [link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/time-tracking) :)